# Linq OrderBy - on duplicate values

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

```
m_ListOfsAllFields.OrderBy(Function(x) x.DisplayOrder)
```

here I have DisplayOrder = 0 for 2 fields, so orderby is messing up and not ordering properly. How can I use orderby to order this collection?

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that `OrderBy` doesn't modify the collection in place but instead creates a new `IEnumerable(Of T)` instance which is correctly ordered.  You need to save the result int the `m_listOfsAllFields` value.

```
m_ListOfsAllFields = m_ListOfsAllFields.OrderBy(Function(x) x.DisplayOrder)
```

If this is an instance of `List(Of T)` though you should just use the `Sort` method directly.

```
m_ListOfsAllFields.Sort(Function (l, r) l.DisplayOrder.CompareTo(r.DisplayOrder))
```

Answer (score 2):

If two objects can have the same value for a property used in one `OrderBy` and you want to further differentiate, add a `ThenBy`.

```
Dim results = sequence.OrderBy(yourFunction).ThenBy(anotherFunction)
```